# iOS 15 UIButton configuration title lineBreakMode not work?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

In iOS 14 or before, if we want to set a `titleLabel's` attributes, we can simply using

```
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

or shrink the title text:

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

But after updated to iOS 15's newest API `UIButton.Configuration`, the above codes are not worked any more, the button is just expand its height, that definitely not the way I want, pls see below:

[image]

Is there any solution to restore `lineBreakMode` or `minimumScaleFactor` when using iOS 15 `UIButton.Configuration`?

Comment: Which ios version you are using?

Comment: version iOS 15.5

Comment: this is a joke issue. tried everything can't get it to work correctly. new "configuration" element is horrible

Answer (score 5):

From Xcode 14.3 beta 1, a new property [titleLineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/4130647-titlelinebreakmode) has been added to `UIButton.Configuration` itself (as opposed to the button's `titleLabel`), and this is exactly what we want.

```swift
var config  = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
config.titleLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
button.configuration = config

// also adjust font size is working properly
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: @matt In my case, set `config.titleLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` is working as expected. The button title is displayed on a single line. and if the text is too long, the end omitted with "..."